# How to make terminal open gui application with focus on it?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, ubuntu-14.04

I might be nitpicking here but it's really annoying when terminal doesn't open application like Chrome, Sublime Text with focus on it if I open them from terminal. I do something like :-

```
shriek@ubuntu ~ $ subl .
```

And then I have to press `Alt + tab` to search that application if I have multiple application running. It defeats the whole purpose of trying to get to my application faster from terminal.

If there's a reason for this kind of behavior can I know why it's like this and also possible workaround for this?

Comment: You may want to include your window manager.  Some directly support auto-focus on open, while others may require additional tools like like [wmctrl](http://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) or [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/xdotool.1.html).

Comment: I'm using the default window manager that comes in Ubuntu 14.04, GNOME with Unity.

Comment: This question is probably more appropriately asked to the [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/) community.  A quick search over there indicates it may be a duplicate though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using `wmctrl` for this. (You can install it with `sudo apt-get install wmctrl`)

Add the following line in your `.bashrc` to open and focus Sublime Text:

```
alias subl="subl && wmctrl -a \"\$(wmctrl -l | grep subl | cut -f 1,2,3,4 -d ' ' --complement)\" 2>&1 >/dev/null"
```

`wmctrl -l` scans your windows and lists the applications you can switch to.
`wmctrl -a WINDOW_TITLE` focus on the application with the specific `WINDOW_TITLE`.
To get the window title I grep and format it with `grep APP_NAME` and `cut`.

You can use this alias for every other application by only changing the alias-name, the command to start the application and with the argument grep is looking for. For example:

```
alias chrome="google-chrome && wmctrl -a \"\$(wmctrl -l | grep Chrome | cut -f 1,2,3,4 -d ' ' --complement)\" 2>&1 >/dev/null"
```

Comment: Wow, that's painful and manual. I see that not even Unity launcher switches the application. But since you did provide a workaround for the problem I'm going to mark this as mentioned.

Answer (score -3):

Only solution i can think of is opening it with the `gksudo` prefix. It can be annoying to type password, but i'm still using it to open any application with GUI from terminal.

Comment: Are you seriously advocating opening GUI applications in privileged mode merely in order for them to receive focus on start-up?  Does that even work?